# how to log into e-mail address?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

Please help solve the problem.

I did the recording system. user enters a name, email and password. registration work (in the database are relevant entries in the table auth_user).

Now I would like to make an authorization form. in which the user enters the email, password. but in my code the error. after entering the email, password authentication is not happening.

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User, UserManager
class UserProfile(User):
    CHOICES_gender = (
        ('0', 'М', ),
        ('1', 'Ж', ),
    )

    gender = models.CharField(
        max_length=10, 
        choices=CHOICES_gender, 
        blank=False,
    )
    phone = models.CharField(
        max_length=50, 
        blank=False,
    )

    objects = UserManager()
```

forms.py:

```
from django import forms
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib.auth.forms import UserCreationForm, AuthenticationForm
from django.forms import ModelForm
import re
from app_accounts.models import UserProfile
class registrationForm(UserCreationForm):   
    username = forms.CharField(
        label='Отображаемое имя',
        help_text='',
        max_length=50, 
        required=True,
    )   
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Email',
        help_text='',
        required=True,
    )

    password1 = forms.CharField(
        label='Пароль',
        help_text='',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )   

    password2 = forms.CharField(
        label='Подтверждение пароля',
        help_text='',
        required=True,
        widget=forms.PasswordInput,
    )   
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = (  
            'username',    
            'email',    
            'password1', 
            'password2',
        )


class authenticationCustomForm(AuthenticationForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(
        label='Email',
        widget=forms.TextInput(),       
    )
    password = forms.CharField(
        label='Пароль', 
        widget=forms.PasswordInput(),
    )
```

Comment: In what way is this authentication not happening? If it's giving you an error, could you post the error?

Comment: authorization in the form of an error message validation

Comment: this is probably not the issue, but in `registrationForm` the `widget`-attribute of your password-fields is declared as: `widget=forms.PasswordInput` and in `authenticationCustomForm` it is declared as: `widget=forms.PasswordInput()`